# Is it possible to force reutrn value from query when no rows found?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple query:

```
Select qty from X where id=....;
```

this query always return 0 or 1 row.
when it return 1 row everything works.
but if it return 0 rows my query fails as `qty` is used in calculations. (This is acatually a Sub query in Select statment).

I need somehow to make sure the query always return 1 row.

I tried:

```
Select coalesce(qty,0) from X where id=....;
```

but it doesn't help as if there are no rows the coalesce is useless.
if no row found it should give `0`

How can I fix it?

Comment: What should be the value of 1 row when query returns no rows

Comment: the value should be 0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT COALESCE( (SELECT qty from X where id=....), 0)
```

if nothing is returned from the inner `SELECT` statement, `COALESCE` will give you `0` in the outer `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select *.a from (
  Select qty, 0 as priority from X where id=....
  Union
  Select 0, 1 as priority
) a
Order By a.priority Asc
Limit 1
```

This select basically ensures that at least one row is returned by adding an additional row to the end and by adding the limit statement we just return the first row.

So now there is the case where at least one row is found and the additional row is added to the end. In this case the first row found (see `->`) will be returned due to the ascending order by priority:

```
   qty priority
-> 1   0 
   3   0
   4   0
   .   .
   0   1
```

And then there is the case where no row is found but the additional row is returned:

```
   qty priority
-> 0   1
```

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro You are right, i edited my answer to provide additional explanation.

Comment: The `coalesce` technique is very handy for a scalar subquery. But in any other case this is the way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT COALESCE((SELECT qty 
                 FROM   x 
                 WHERE  id = @MyIdVar), 1)
```

Comment: Syntax error, because of `select qty from X where id=....;`. Remove `;` from subquery

Comment: @lad2025 its dummy data not actual so i have not removed that. also not only need to remove ; but also need to assign some proper value in where id=?

Comment: The point is that `...` means missing value and `;` is part of query. It doesn't matter it is dummy or not. Do it correctly [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a627e/4/0)

Answer (score 0):

Without using `COALESCE()`

```
 select qty from X where id=1 UNION SELECT 0 order by qty desc limit 1
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a627e/5)

Comment: Without an `order by` the result is not foreseeable. Check `select 1 union select 0 limit 1;`

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Thanks for the nit picking !!

Answer (score 0):

If no records found then its return 'No rows found'

```
if not exists(Select * from table where condition=...)
Begin
Select * from table where condition=...
End
Else
Begin
Select 'No rows found'
End
```

Whenever you use this you will get record else no record found message.